# Set dynamic values for properties in a a constant object react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have  Const like this in my config.service.ts file

```
export const mysettings={
   userid:"12324",
  conf:{
     sessionDuration:30,
    mac:"LON124"
  }
}
```

I am using this constant in some components

But instead of hardcoding those values in const I need to get that at runtime from JSON file in my public folder

So I have a function like this as well

```
async getConfig(){
   const data=await     fetch("./data/data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => return json );

}
```

So in my data.json files I have those values for the const and I need these values in that JSON file to updated or the JSON file itself sometimes replaced.

Please help me how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Context and ContextProvider to load your data from json file, set it to state variable and just pass it to Context consumers:

DataContext.tsx:

```ts
import { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import asyncData from "./asyncData";

interface IData {
  userid: string;
  conf: {
    sessionDuration: number;
    mac: string;
  };
}

interface IContextValue {
  data: IData;
}

const StateContext = createContext<IContextValue>(null!);

export function DataContextProvider(props: PropsWithChildren) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<IData>(undefined!);

  useEffect(() => {
    asyncData.then((json) => setData(json)).catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  // Optionally - wrap with useMemo
  const contextValue: IContextValue = {
    data: data
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {data && props.children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function useDataContext() {
  const context = useContext(StateContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useDataContext must be used within the DataContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
}
```

Updates to index.tsx:

```ts
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { DataContextProvider } from "./DataContext";

import App from "./App";
import asyncData from "./asyncData";

asyncData.then((config) => {
  console.log("Config is fetched before render: ", config);

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
  const root = createRoot(rootElement!);

  root.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <DataContextProvider>
        <App />
      </DataContextProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
});
```

Usage:

```
import useDataContext from "./DataContext";

export default function App() {
  const { data } = useDataContext();
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
```

asyncData.ts:

```
const asyncData = fetch("./data/data.json").then((response) => response.json());

export default asyncData;
```

[image: Edit React context with json file loading]

Comment: That's really great.. But one question.. if I need to use that const in index.tsx itself how can I achieve that. Its like before render I've few functions required to execute first which also needed that const. Is it possible

Comment: @SandeepThomas Updated my answer to show how to use it inside index.tsx itself. Sandbox is also updated.

Comment: Wawww.. Superb.. thanks a lot mate.  thats great